# bigQuery Google Drive Sheets multiple worksheets in one sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-bigquery

I have created 3 Google Cloud bigQuery tables mapping to 3 worksheets in a single Google Sheets sheet. I have named the 3 tables according to the 3 worksheet names, and I can run SQL queries against the tables.

My problem is that the results from the query always show the records in the first worksheet within the spreadsheet, not the second or third worksheet.

Is it possible to associate BigQuery tables to different worksheets of the same Google Sheets document? If not, is the only solution to have 3 separate sheet documents each with the first worksheet being the one with the records that BigQuery will query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is currently not supported. BigQuery can only query the first sheet. You can follow https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905674 if you're interested in this feature.

Comment: Thanks, I have now split my 3 worksheets into 3 independent sheets, and made sure the one to query is the first one (left-most in the worksheet tab).

Comment: I have seen that there is a new possible solution implemented by Google dated May 2018.

Comment: I added a new question relating to the feature described in Comment12 of your link here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50627488/bigquery-google-drive-query-multiple-sheets-with-googlesheetsoptions-range