# bigQuery Google Drive query multiple sheets with googleSheetsOptions range

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-bigquery

I have created a Google Sheets spreadsheet with two worksheets, called `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P1WH7cwVDaG6k-OQxKVXtnjBXI1NGFYvHD6IxCRFsZc/edit?usp=sharing

`Sheet1` has columns `col1` and `col2` in row 1, and `Sheet2` has columns `col3` and `col4` in row 1.

I would like to be able to query both sheets using the command-line bigQuery interface.
It seems like this was not possible until a recent feature added in May 2018:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905674#comment12

I tried to replicate what this comment describes, but I can't get it to work. Here is what I've done so far:

The description of the new feature shows an example `google_sheets_tabeledef.json` that looks like this:

```
{
  "autodetect": false,
  "sourceFormat": "GOOGLE_SHEETS", 
  "sourceUris": [
    "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  ],
  "maxBadRecords": 1,
  "googleSheetsOptions":
  {
    "range": "test_sheet!A1:B20",
    "skipLeadingRows": 0
  },
  "schema" : {
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "col1",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "col2",
        "type": "int64"
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

Given my spreadsheet with two sheets, `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`, I created their respective tables in my bigQuery account,
then I tried to query each of them via the command-line `bq query`. It works as shown for `Sheet1`:

```
bq query --format=csv --use_legacy_sql=false 'SELECT * FROM `cegx-test-project1.multi_sheet_test.Sheet1`' 2>/dev/null

col1,col2
col1,col2
foo,bar
abc,def
```

And if I try the same for `Sheet2`, in absence of the external_table_definition, it shows:

```
bq query --format=csv --use_legacy_sql=false 'SELECT * FROM `cegx-test-project1.multi_sheet_test.Sheet2`' 2>/dev/null

col3,col4
col1,col2
foo,bar
abc,def
```

So it basically reverts to the first worksheet instead of querying `Sheet2`. So far, as expected.

I have then created an equivalent `google_sheets_sheet2_tabledef.json` file like this:

```
{
  "autodetect": true, 
  "sourceFormat": "GOOGLE_SHEETS", 
  "sourceUris": [
    "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P1WH7cwVDaG6k-OQxKVXtnjBXI1NGFYvHD6IxCRFsZc"
  ],
  "maxBadRecords": 1,
  "googleSheetsOptions":
  {
    "range": "Sheet2!A1:B10",
    "skipLeadingRows": 0
  },
  "schema" : {
    "fields": [
{"name":"col3","type":"string"},
{"name":"col4","type":"string"}
    ]
  }
}
```

Notice how in the `range` parameter, I am pointing to `Sheet2!A1:B10`.

If I try to query the table again, now with the external_table_definition flag, I get:

```
bq query --external_table_definition="Sheet2::/tmp/google_sheets_sheet2_tabledef.json" --format=csv --use_legacy_sql=false 'SELECT * FROM `cegx-test-project1.multi_sheet_test.Sheet2`' 2>/dev/null                                             

col3,col4
col1,col2
foo,bar
abc,def
```

So I still get the results from `Sheet1` even with the external definition file pointing to the range in `Sheet2`.

Any ideas where the issue is?

Comment: @hua-zhang I couldn't get the instructions on https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905674#comment12 to work, so I created a new question here.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. Li is looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the command you used to query from an temporary external table definition was not referring to the external table.

If you change the command to the following, it should work as expected:

bq query --external_table_definition="Sheet2::/tmp/google_sheets_sheet2_tabledef.json" --format=csv --use_legacy_sql=false 'SELECT * FROM `Sheet2`' 2>/dev/null

Comment: Ah yes, understood, I was still referring to the table as defined in bigQuery, not the one in the external_table_definition. It now works. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @li-tan I got it working yesterday, now I wrote a script to automate table creation and tabledef creation in a json file and I get an error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50643699/bigquery-error-while-reading-data-error-message-row-1-has-only-1-columns-whil

Comment: can the equivalent to the command-line above also be done in google apps scripts? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery