# bigQuery Error while reading data, error message: Row 1 has only 1 columns, while 2 is needed

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-bigquery

I created a json file to define a table in Google bigQuery that is linked to a Google Sheets spreadsheet:

```
{
  "autodetect": true, 
  "sourceFormat": "GOOGLE_SHEETS", 
  "sourceUris": [
    "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P1WH7cwVDaG6k-OQxKVXtnjBXI1NGFYvHD6IxCRFsZc"
  ],
  "maxBadRecords": 1,
  "googleSheetsOptions":
  {
    "range": "Sheet2!A1:B10",
    "skipLeadingRows": 0
  },
  "schema" : {
    "fields": [
{"name":"col3","type":"string"},
{"name":"col4","type":"string"}
    ]
  }
}
```

When I query it with this bq command line:

```
bq query --external_table_definition="Sheet2::/home/avilella/LIMS/test.json" --format=csv --use_legacy_sql=false 'SELECT * FROM Sheet2'
```

I get this error:

```
BigQuery error in query operation: Error processing job 'cegx-test-project1:bqjob_r30ad5155bcd0a174_00000163bb575bcf_1': Error while reading table: Sheet2, error message: Sheets table encountered too many
errors, giving up. Rows: 2; errors: 2. Please look into the error stream for more details.
Failure details:
- 1P1WH7cwVDaG6k-OQxKVXtnjBXI1NGFYvHD6IxCRFsZc: Error while reading
data, error message: Row 1 has only 1 columns, while 2 is needed.
- 1P1WH7cwVDaG6k-OQxKVXtnjBXI1NGFYvHD6IxCRFsZc: Error while reading
data, error message: Row 2 has only 1 columns, while 2 is needed.
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @li-tan I got an error when trying this today. This is related to the previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50627488/bigquery-google-drive-query-multiple-sheets-with-googlesheetsoptions-range

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is to have empty cells in Google Sheets. I was able to run the same command after add some string in `col4`. Notice that there is [`allowJaggedRows`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.load.allowJaggedRows) option for loading configuration in Bigquery to accept  missing trailing optional columns but it only apply to CSV and in [this document](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/reading#read_a_single_range) about Google Sheets reading process states

> Empty trailing rows and columns are omitted.

I think the best solution for this case is to substitute empty cells to some other values. For instance, 'null'.

Answer (score 1):

From the Sheet2 on your test spreadsheet, I saw there is only 1 column in both the 2nd and 3rd rows, so both are 'bad' rows because the table schema has 2 fields as specified in the external table def json. Also because the maxBadRecords is set to 1, query can succeed with at most 1 had row, but since you've got two bad rows, the query failed as expected.

Comment: BTW, we will be rolling out a change so that if all trailing columns are NULLABLE in the schema, those columns don't have to have values present in the sheet. With this change, in the earlier example, the query would not fail since both the two columns are NULLABLE in your table schema.

Comment: And we will let you know once this change has been completely rolled out.